# Extract a number in a list and put it into other list element if it qualifies certain conditions using java

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a problem statement this is kind of a business logic and i want to get your opinion on this, how would you approach this kind of scenario, just wanted to know the best possible scenario that's it.

Lets say you have list of elements and this list of elements have a class which basically says this is a Hardware item or a service item. I also have other materials but i am mainly focusing on these two.

I am maintaining a single class. called Material and have attributes like `isHardwareItem`,`isserviceItem`,`entryNum`, `id` , `Product`.

`isHardwareItem` -> true for Hardware item and false for all other items.
`isserviceItem` -> true for service item and false for all other items.
`entryNum` -> generates a unique number for each item if the item added to cart
`id` -> an integer that will be generated only if customer adds service item along with hardware item and it will be same for each Hardware + serviceItem so that i can relate. for example

> Hardwareitem  - id = 0 , entryNum=1

> ServiceItem - id = 0, entryNum = 2

`Product` -> another class which holds product name, description and etc.

**The Problem**

if customer adds a service item along with the hardware item i need to attach the `entryNum` of hardware item to the service item along with serviceItem attributes.

**My Approach**

first checks the id, if the id generated that means customer added both hardware & service item. get the `entryNum` of the hardware and store it in a Map.

key would be Id & Value would be entryNumber of hardware item.

then the iteration happens on the added entries and a request will be created to send the materials to the external api. during this if i encounter a servicematerial with same id i will attach it with the entryNum of hardware material & make the request and send this in the api.

I have the above solution but it is costly because literally the iteration is happening twice. do any of you have a better solution than mine ? Please drop your thoughts.

Have a great day . :)

Comment: Not solving the problem, but for maintainability you could make the `isHardwareItem`, `isServiceItem` and so on fields a method and just store a `int type` field. Say `0` corresponds to hardwareItem and `1` corresponds to serviceItem. Then `isHardwareItem()` would just return `type==0` and `isServiceItem()` would just return `type==1`. When adding more types, you don't have to clutter your class with all these fields and most importantly, you don't need to set every single one of these fields.